# Just get error messages text from modelstate in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to return just error messages text in web api in ASP.Net Core 2.2,

I use the following code to return values:

```
 if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState.Values);
            }
```

and i get the following response:

```
[
    {
        "childNodes": null,
        "children": null,
        "key": "user.Username",
        "subKey": {
            "buffer": "user.Username",
            "offset": 5,
            "length": 8,
            "value": "Username",
            "hasValue": true
        },
        "isContainerNode": false,
        "rawValue": null,
        "attemptedValue": null,
        "errors": [
            {
                "exception": null,
                "errorMessage": "Username is required"
            }
        ],
        "validationState": 1
    }
]
```

I need just error messages text for response, like this:

```
{
'data': [
Username is required,
Password is required,
],

'status': 'error'
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just using `return BadRequest(ModelState)` instead of `ModelState.Values`?

Comment: @CalC yes, but i can't get just message texts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, since you're using ASP.NET Core 2.2, you should really be using the `ApiController` attribute:

```
[ApiController]
public class FooApiController : ControllerBase
```

With that, ASP.NET Core actually takes care of bad requests for you automatically, so you don't even need this check in your action at all.

Otherwise, you should use:

```
ModelState.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.Errors);
```

Or if you just want the errors alone, not keyed to the individual properties:

```
ModelState.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors);
```

Comment: I use ```ModelState.SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors);``` and then whit foreact get item.ErrorMessage, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use bellow code to get the list of errors

```
var query = from state in ModelState.Values
            from error in state.Errors
            select error.ErrorMessage;

var errorMessages = query.ToList();
```

the variable errorMessages is an array like bellow:

```
[ "OTP is required", "Password & ConfirmPassword is not matched" ]
```